# Cyrillic symbols in SELECT query PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot (Aiogram, Python), which is connected to PostgreSQL database.

If user enters a some username (in Cyrillic, Russian or Ukrainian), bot should return full information about this user, stored in database.

The problem is: when bot making query to the database, with username for example “Сергій”, it returns nothing, although information exists in database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username = 'Сергій';
```

I found out that problem is in symbols like 'c' or 'i', that looks similar, but have different hex code in UTF-8. If we'll change query this way all works fine

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username LIKE '_ерг_й';
```

I've already changed database encoding to UTF-8, but still have this problem.
If i copy username directly from database and paste it into bot's input field - it works.

Here's main fragments of my code:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def username_input_handler(message: Message):
    username = message.text

    answer_text = await db.search_by_username(username)
    await message.answer(text=answer_text)

# database class
class Database():
    ...
    async def search_by_username(username):
        query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE $1"
        user = await self.pool.execute(query, username)
        return user
    ...
```

UPDATE:

Problem occurs only when I am querying the 'users' table. This table's data was imported from a `.txt` file.

Running the same queries against another table works fine.

Comment: Try a national character literal, `N'Сергій'`.

Comment: @jarlh, it has no effect. I've tried to make query directly to database, via console, added N-prefix. I suppose, it could be the problem of how my database file was filled. For example, there might occured an error, in process of formatting source users file, and letters like 'c' or 'i' (that are similar in Eng and Ukr) has been encoded wrong. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users enter the exact same characters as are in the database, the query will work, but obviously they aren't. You probably need similarity search:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON users USING gist (username gist_trgm_ops);

SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY username <-> 'Сергій'
LIMIT 1;
```

This will probably not be satisfactory for short names like `Сергій`. If both `С` and `і` are the wrong character, there is only one trigram left to match: `ерг`. And this may not find the closest match that you are looking for.

You may need to write a function `cyrillic_normalize` that replaces every non-Cyrillic letter with the "closest" Cyrillic letter, like

```
CREATE FUNCTION cyrillic_normalize(text) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql AS
$$SELECT translate ($1, 'Ci', 'Сі')$$;
```

where the first string contains the Latin letters and the second the corresponding Cyrillic ones.

Then change your query to

```
WHERE cyrillic_normalize(username) = cyrillic_normalize('Сергій')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need something different. I need to return all information about user by username: age, position and etc. So WHERE statement is neccessary. Even if i filtering records in Database " username='Іван' " it couldn't find this row. But if i change 'I' letter (ukrainian) to 'I' (latin),  voila, database returns me required row :) Same story happens with 'C'.

Comment: But my query will return only a single row. Write `SELECT *` and you will get the whole row. But it won't work so well with short names, see my extended answer.